# Why is a Jenkins script job failing to use proper AWS credentials?

Tags: jenkins, amazon-iam

I have a simple jenkins job that just runs `aws ssm send-command` and it fails with:

"An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the SendCommand operation: User: arn:aws:sts::1234567890:assumed-role/jenkins-live/i-1234567890abc is not authorized to perform: ssm:SendCommand on resource: arn:aws:ssm:us-east-1:1234567890:document/my-document-name"

However, the IAM permissions are correct. To prove it, I directly SSH onto that instance and run the exact same ssm command, and it works. I verify it's using the instance role by running `aws sts get-caller-identity` and it returns `arn:aws:sts::1234567890:assumed-role/jenkins-live/i-1234567890abc` which is the same user mentioned in the error message.

So indeed, this assumed role can run the command.

I even modified the jenkins job to run `aws sts get-caller-identity` first, and it outputs the same user json.

Does jenkins do some caching that I am unaware of? Why would I get that `AccessDeniedException` if that jenkins-live user can run the command otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

First, install the [AWS Credentials](https://plugins.jenkins.io/aws-credentials/) and [AWS Steps](https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-aws/) plugins and register your AWS key and secret access key in Jenkins credential store. Then, the next steps depends if you're using a freestyle or a declarative/scripted pipeline.

- If you're using a freestyle pipeline: On "Build Environment", click on "Use secret text(s) or file(s)" and follow the next steps. After that, you're gonna have your credentials as variables in your pipeline;
- If you're using a declarative/scripted pipeline: Enclose your `aws` calls with a `withAWS` block, something like this:

```
withAWS(region: 'us-east-1', credentials: 'my-pretty-credentials') {
    // let's explode something
}
```

Best regards.

Comment: The issue was not with the credentials (`sts get-caller-identity` shows that) but rather with AWS IAM itself. I was on a support call and we found that if I use an attached managed policy instead of an inline policy, it worked. They're perplexed why and are investigating on their end. FWIW, this IAM role has many attached policies.